# MapView inside custom cell delegate issue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, mkmapview

I have created a tableview with a cell that has a mapView. I'm adding the annotation and trying to make a route between them. I have made the same thing with the same code from another view controller which is working fine but couldn't make the same in the tableview custom cell that has the map. It is not entering inside the `viewForAnnotation` or `rendererForOverlay`. I have enabled the mapDelegate to the view controller. So please where would be my issue?

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell8") as! MapViewTableViewCell
cell.mapView.delegate = self //Tested didn't work
    cell.mapView.setRegion(cell.mapView.regionThatFits(MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(sourceLocation.placemark.coordinate, 1800, 1800)), animated: true)

    cell.calculateRoute(cell.endLocations, secondArray: cell.waypointLocations)

        for item in cell.endLocations {

           let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = item.placemark.coordinate
            if cell.endLocations.indexOf(item) == 0 {
                annotation.title = "start"
            }
            else {
                annotation.title = "end"
            }
            cell.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        }

        return cell
```

And I have made and extension for map

```
extension CarViewController : MKMapViewDelegate{

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    if (annotation.title! == "start") {

        let pinAnnotation = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "identifier")
        pinAnnotation.pinColor = .Green
        return pinAnnotation
    }
    else if (annotation.title! == "end") {

        let pinAnnotation = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "identifier")
        pinAnnotation.pinColor = .Purple
        return pinAnnotation
    }
    return nil
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {

    if overlay is MKPolyline {
        let polylineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        polylineRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        polylineRenderer.alpha = 0.80
        polylineRenderer.lineWidth = 5
        return polylineRenderer
    }

        return MKPolylineRenderer()
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you setting the mapDelegate? it should be right after the "let cell" declaration, before you actually use the map.

Comment: @TiagoLira I have setted directly after the let but it didn't work :(

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this? I'm having a similar issue.